# What is the meaning of st_coordinates()'s return values in R?

Tags: r, geo, r-sf

Here is the explanation of st_coordinates() method's return values in sf package of R.

matrix with coordinates (X, Y, possibly Z and/or M) in rows, possibly followed by integer indicators L1,...,L3 that point out to which structure the coordinate belongs; for POINT this is absent (each coordinate is a feature), for LINESTRING L1 refers to the feature, for MULTIPOLYGON L1 refers to the main ring or holes, L2 to the ring id in the MULTIPOLYGON, and L3 to the simple feature.

Could you please explain about L1,2,3?

Comment: Think of them as `id` columns. For a LINESTRING, L1 will have the same value for every point in each LINESTRING. For POLYGONS, L1 will have the same value for every point in a POLYGON, and L2 will have the same values for every point in each LINESTRING within the POLYGON (because a polygon is made up of one or many linestrings).

Comment: Thanks to your explanation, I was able to solve my problem. Your comment was very helpful to me.